# KAFKA: Connection to node failed authentication due to: Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with SASL mechanism SCRAM-SHA-256

Tags: apache-kafka, properties, apache-zookeeper, sasl-scram

I've been trying to add a SASL Authentication to my Kafka Brokers using SASL_PLAINTEXT SCRAM-SHA-256 for a while, but without any success. I keep getting the following error on Kafka's logfile.

> ERROR [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=0] Connection to node 0 failed
>   authentication due to: Authentication failed due to invalid
>   credentials with SASL mechanism SCRAM-SHA-256
>   (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient).

But I've been following Kafka docs on SCRAM Config to the letter and not getting anywhere near of successfully achieving this to work.

I registred an admin user on Zookeeper using kafka-configs.sh like below:

```
bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --add-config 'SCRAM-SHA-256=[password=admin-secret],SCRAM-SHA-512=[password=admin-secret]' --entity-type users --entity-name admin
```

Here are part of my server.properties where I configure SCRAM-SHA-256.

```
broker.id=50
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-256
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=SCRAM-SHA-256
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://172.16.3.21:9092
advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://172.16.3.21:9092
listener.name.sasl_plaintext.scram-sha-256.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required \
    username="admin" \
    password="admin-secret";
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. Any luck?

Answer (score -3):

Generating CA on one node and copying it to other node manually worked for me

### STEP 1- RUN this on each node

keytool -keystore server.keystore.jks -alias kafka -dname "cn=kafka, ou=**it**, o=**stackoverflow**, l=**alpha**, st=**beta**, c=**IN**" -storepass test123 -validity 365 -keyalg RSA -genkey -ext SAN=DNS:**kafka-host1**,DNS:**kafka-host2**,DNS:**kafka-host3**,DNS:localhost,DNS:kafka

#### STEP 2 - verify the cert

keytool -list -v -keystore server.keystore.jks

#### STEP 3 - generate this once on single node and copy is to other nodes.

openssl req -new -x509 -keyout ca-key -out ca-cert -days 365 -subj "/C=IN/ST=**beta**/O=**stackoverflow**/OU=**it**/L=**alpha**/CN=**kafka**"

#### REMAINING STEPS ARE BELOW NEED TO RUN ON EACH NODES

keytool -keystore server.truststore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert -storepass test123 -noprompt

keytool -keystore client.truststore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert -storepass test123 -noprompt

keytool -keystore server.keystore.jks -alias kafka -certreq -file cert-file -storepass test123

openssl x509 -req -CA ca-cert -CAkey ca-key -in cert-file -out cert-signed -days 3650 -CAcreateserial -passin pass:test123

keytool -keystore server.keystore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert -storepass test123 -noprompt

keytool -keystore server.keystore.jks -alias kafka -import -file cert-signed -storepass test123 -noprompt